# Writing macro for generating functions / multimethods

Tags: clojure, macros

I am currenlty trying to provide a DSL by using Clojure macros. The users of my library must be able to extend it using that DSL. The library provides a multi-method and some baseline implementations using defmethod for some certain commands out of the box. Let's say, we have a multimethod: 

`(defmulti command command-name)`

and some provided commands by library like:

`(defmethod command "say-hello" [arg] (println "hello" arg))
(defmethod command "say-bye" [arg] (println "bye" arg))`

The idea is to write a macro which generates these defmethods, so the users don't need to write defmethods themselves, instead, use my DSL. Regarding to this, I wrote the following macro: 

`` (defmacro add-command [command-name command-impl]
   `(defmethod command ~command-name '[arg] ~@command-impl)) ``

What I get is, whenever I use my macro with, `(add-command "new-command" (print "new-command"))` the following exception  "**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException**: Parameter declaration do should be a vector".

If I expand the macro:

`(clojure.core/defmethod com.foo/on-error "new-command" [] (println "starting"))`

Everything looks OK, except the argument vector, which is empty after expanding.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the implicit `arg` to exist in the body you need to write:

```
(defmacro add-command [command-name command-impl]
   `(defmethod command ~command-name [~'arg] ~@command-impl))
```

instead. Anaphoric macros (macros that intoduce fixed names like `arg` here) are generally unusual/frowned upon in Clojure.

Please note that macroexpanding your example I get a different (and expected) result from yours:

```
(clojure.core/defmethod user/command "new-command" (quote [user/arg]) print "new-command")
```

Comment: I don't think the following is necessary: `~'arg`. Is there a reason you don't write directly `arg` in the backquoted form? Namespace issues?

Comment: Well, testing reveals that I "Can't use qualified name as parameter" with the `arg` only. It makes sense now :-)

Comment: @coredump Yup, it's Clojure approach to macro hygiene: making hard to introduce names by accident.